# Google Apps Script: Retrieving Grid Item Response Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

No matter what I do, this returns an undefined object for "Logger.log(medItemResponse);".

```
function updateMedicationNumbers() {
  var lastFormResponse = getLastForm();
  getMedItemResponse(lastFormResponse);
}

function getLastForm(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponseArray = form.getResponses();
  var lastFormResponse = formResponseArray[formResponseArray.length-1];
  Logger.log(lastFormResponse);
  return lastFormResponse;

}

function getMedItemResponse(lastFormResponse){
  var responseItems = lastFormResponse.getItemResponses();
  Logger.log(responseItems);
  for (var i = 0; i < responseItems.length; i++){
      var responseItem = responseItems[i].getItem();
      if(responseItem.getTitle() == "Individual Meds"){
        var medItemResponse = responseItems[i].getResponse();
      }
    }
  Logger.log(medItemResponse);
  }
```

Here's the documentation for .getResponse();

Gets the answer that the respondent submitted. For most types of question items, this returns a String. For CheckboxItem questions, this returns a String[] array containing the responder's choices. The order of the strings in the array may vary. For GridItem questions, this returns a String[] array in which the answer at index n corresponds to the question at row n + 1 in the grid. If a respondent did not answer a question in the grid, that answer is returned as ''. For CheckboxGridItem questions, this returns a String[][] array in which the answers at row index n corresponds to the question at row n + 1 in the checkbox grid. If a respondent did not answer a question in the grid, that answer is returned as ''.

Return

Object — a String or String[] or String[][] of answers to the question item

Comment: You should have a `break` in the loop inside the block that runs for truthy `responseItem.getTitle() == "Individual Meds"`  It should be:  `if(responseItem.getTitle() == "Individual Meds"){var medItemResponse = responseItems[i].getResponse();break; }`  If there is only one title named `Individual Meds` then there is no reason to keep looping once that match is found.  Put a `Logger.log()` statement in your code that shows the result of the truthy test.  `Logger.log(responseItem.getItem().getTitle() == "Individual Meds")`  You should see one true print out to the logs.If not-no match found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with another form and it seems to work but I'm not sure if it will work for you.

```
function getMedItemResponse(lastFormResponse){
  var responseItems = lastFormResponse.getItemResponses();
  Logger.log(responseItems);
  for (var i = 0; i < responseItems.length; i++){
      var responseItem = responseItems[i];
      if(responseItem.getItem().getTitle() == "Individual Meds"){
        var medItemResponse = responseItems[i].getResponse();
      }
    }
  Logger.log(medItemResponse);
  }
```